# Auto Authorization using localStorage and Websocket

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, server, authorization

I have a project I'm working on which is a single-page dynamic web app which uses Javascript and a Websocket to retrieve data from a Golang server. I've implemented the auto-authorization method described in [this article](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice). I was referred to that article from [this one](https://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) which at the end mentions to check out the first article I linked (just in case you were wondering what that first article was "improving" upon).

This is how my setup works:

- Client loads app, and before anything dynamic loads, client connects to Websocket
- Client sends login, device token, and session token through Websocket (of course if they were logged in before) from localStorage
- Golang Websocket server checks if database has matching login, device token, session token, client's browser/version, etc (I get a few other pieces of data to match a device with the user's HTTP request for extra security)
- If there's a match, Golang generates a new session token, updates the database match with it, and sends it back to the client
- Client gets session token and updates it in their localStorage to use the next time they load the site

Now, don't get me wrong. Everything is working great... but there's **one problem**:

If a user logs in, then reloads the page a bunch of times as fast as they can, sometimes the websocket and server don't have enough time to get the user's next session token back to them. This of course causes their tokens to expire and be removed from the database and notifies the user that their credentials have either been expired or stolen (which really doesn't look good from a business standpoint).

I have some thoughts on solutions, but none seem promising in scalability and for the long run.

All thoughts and solutions on the matter are appreciated!

Comment: After login the session is established, isn't it? Why would you regenerate the remember-me tokens while the session is still active? You'd only do that once, after some time of inactivity when the session expired. So you should only risk missing the remember-me update once in a blue moon.

Comment: Also, using browser fingerprinting for authentication is questionable. I don't want to get logged out after browser update (my browser version is now different from your database entry). It's much better to cryptographically sign the tokens, with hmac for instance.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not, but the websocket handshake supports cookies.  You can implement the schedme described in the document without using local storage.

Comment: @Peter You know, I forgot about session... That's a good idea. And about the browser fingerprinting, I don't use the version numbers. Just a combination of things that stay persistent on a machine/browser which I can obtain through their HTTP request to the websocket. You should post the answer for using session to keep from trying to auto-login more than once!

Comment: @CeriseLimón I don't want to use cookies, since they expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login you should send two tokens to the browser, a short-lived session token (say, one hour) and a long-lived remember-me token (say, 30 days). The session token's TTL is reset to one hour every time the browser shows activity, but its value does not change.

If and only if the session cookie has expired (or is otherwise invalid), the remember-me cookie is traded for a new, authenticated, session. This does not happen when reloading the page, only after the browser has been inactive for more than an hour.

Prolonging the session happens purely on the server side. Only when trading the remember-me token is it critical that the browser receives and stores the new session token.

You should not delete the remember-me token from the database immediately after first use. If I start my browser it restores previously open tabs, which may include multiple for your site. Consequently, your server will receive multiple requests (or websocket connections) almost simultaneously and those requests race for the new session-token.

At my workplace we allow remember-me tokens to be used for up to two minutes after first use, and at most N times, whichever happens first. That fixes races and allows for retries in case of connectivity issues.

Comment: Ok, let me get this straight... you open your browser that had 3 tabs of my site open. They all send a request for a new session token at the same time with the same credentials and they all get back a different new session token? Wouln't you need some sort of synchronization to ensure your browser received and stored the very last token created and the websocket server only store that same last one?

Comment: @newplayer65, you would respond with the same session token every time. You can store it alongside the remember-me token when the first request comes in. Most storage backends offer atomic updates, otherwise you have to synchronize yourself (on the server).